# Shell command to find all C/C++ files that have a main function?

Tags: shell

I need to find, within a directory and its subdirectories, all C/C++ programs that include a main function.

What would be the shell command to do so?  Just search for "main" should give false positives for cases such as variable name "main_a" etc.

Comment: `that include a main function.` - are you looking for files that *define* `main()`?

Comment: So search the for the _whole word_ `main` - `main` followed not by `_` or a letter.

Comment: Related to _main_a_ example, also false positives for "main()" within comments.  Are you running a Linux system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single generic answer. It depends on how the 'main' prototype is written. If the 'main' are written with a prototype `int main(...)` on a single line, possible to find most of them located with:

```
find . -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cc' -o -name '*.cxx' | xargs grep 'int \+main *('
```

Of course, any solution that does not parse the code will generate false positive/negative. E.g., the grep will find commented `main` prototypes, and will not identify places when the declaration is split over multiple lines: the `int` is placed in a different line from the `main`, or the '(int argc, ...)` is on a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

Similar args with `find` could be used as shown in the other answer. This one limits file selection to regular files, runs `ctags` for some parsing and may generate more accurate  results:

```
find . -regex '.*\.cc?' -type f -exec ctags -f - {} + | awk '$1 == "main" { print $2 }'
```

Yes, this solution requires certain utilities/features; they are not expected to be found on absolutely every system.